# Create a google app engine account without a domain name

Tags: google-app-engine

I dont have a domain name which is hosted in google or any other place.  I want to create a developer account in google for testing  single  sign on. While creating a trial account google is asking me for a domain name. Is there any way to get a trial edition without purchasing a domain name ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just go to [appspot.com](https://appengine.google.com/) and sign in with your account. No domain is needed or so.

Answer (score 0):

With single sign on you talk about OpenId or oauth with a specific library like [Simple Auth](https://github.com/crhym3/simpleauth)  or google standard authentication ?
Can you provide more details ?

Olivier

Comment: I am trying to do single sign on with salesforce